# How To Change VS2008 Theme Like VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, themes

I want to chamge my vs 2008 theme like 2010 theme here is a picture of theme that i want to use in my vs2008(i mean i want to change whole IDE theme not just code background,....)
[image]

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is written in WPF which handles theming differently to Visual Studio 2008 so you might not be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download a .vssettings file containing the theme, among and then import it in visual studio using tools > import and export settings

Comment: i downloaded some of them but it just changes the background color of code